# Joint Density Function for unit circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I just had a small clarification about the joint density function of the unit circle. So, is the support set of such a setup $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ ?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{it is.}$

Comment: The joint density for such a disk $D$ with radius 1 is $\frac{1}{\pi} \chi_D$ where $\chi_D(M)=1^\  \iff \ M \in D$

Comment: Unit circle? Then you are dealing with $x^2+y^2=1$ and a density function does not exist. This because the Lebesgue measure of it takes value 0. For unit disk things are different.